# Create a std::stringbuf based on a array of char

Tags: c++

I'm facing a problem in my code :
I try to create a stringbuf with my input , which is a char array.
I tried this :

> `void fonction(char *data){ 
>   std::stringbuf buffer;
>   buffer.str(data);
>   }`

But i've got an errors at compilation " basic_string::_S_construct null not valid "

if someone knows how to fix this problem ...

Comment: Are you including `<sstream>` in this source file?

Comment: Compilation errors typically point to a line; which line does this error point to?

Comment: this error doesn't give the line because i use this code as a lib.so

Comment: and yes @WhozCraig i'm including  <sstream>

Comment: "this error doesn't give the line"  - huh? You claim "i've got an errors at compilation". Linking and *running* against a .so has nothing to do with a compilation error. Past the **full**, *exact* text of the error message into your question please. The error message you posted looks like something that would happen *at run-time*, and if so, have you checked to see if `data` is NULL?

Comment: Please paste the full error message. And give us a compileable example.

Comment: actually i found the solution , i have to use the method " sputn(char * data, int size) " of the objet stringbuf !